# Rails ActiveRecord includes with condition for the second query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have three models: `Sale`, `Product` and `Client`. A sale belongs to both a product and a client, each of which has many sales. Client also has many products through sales (basically products which have ever been sold to that client). The query for `client.products` is

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "sales" ON "products"."id" = "sales"."product_id" WHERE "sales"."client_id" = $1
```

So far, so good. Now I want to eager load sales for products which belong to a client (`client.products.includes(:sales)`), which correctly fetches all sales for each product for this client, like this:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "sales" ON "products"."id" = "sales"."product_id" WHERE "sales"."client_id" = $1;
SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."product_id" IN (...)
```

The problem is I would like to only fetch sales which belong to that client. The query should look like this:

```
SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "sales" ON "products"."id" = "sales"."product_id" WHERE "sales"."client_id" = $1;
SELECT "sales".* FROM "sales" WHERE "sales"."client_id" = $1 AND "sales"."product_id" IN (...)
```

I've tried doing

```
client.products.includes(:sales).where(sales: { client: client } })
```

and

```
client.products.includes(:sales).where(products: { sales: { client: client } })
```

but unfortunately it only alters the first query like this:

```
WHERE "sales"."client_id" = $1 AND "sales"."client_id" = $2
```

Both $1 and $2 are the same value.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with `includes`? If so how do I do it?

Comment: You mean client.includes(:sales)

Comment: No, not really. That would be all sales for that client. I want all sales grouped with all products for that client.

Comment: try `client.sales.includes(:product)`

Comment: That gives an array of sales, not an array of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sales = client.sales.includes(:product)`

This will return you all the sales and eager load products for a sale/client.

To get the products you can loop through the sales

```
sales.each do |sale| 
  sale.product
end
```

Edit

You can group sales by products

`products_with_sales = sales.group_by(&:product)`

this will return you an array of hashes

```
key = product
value = [sales]
```

then you can perform you calculations

```
products_with_sales.each do |product, sales|
  # sales.map { ... }
  # sales.sum(&:method)
end
```

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase. For simplicity assume I want to list all products this client has ever bought, and then for example a sum of values of all sales for each product separately. This cannot be simplified to SQL sum, though, because actually there's more data I need to work with. This is not the solution. In my post I put the exact SQL query I need to achieve.

Comment: Great, now this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for staying with me and trying to understand my issue :).